# Is there a way to automatically install vmware tools on new Windows server VMs upon VM Creation in vCenter7?

Tags: backup, virtualization, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, vmware-tools

We are running vCenter7 to manage our virtual machine infrastructure, i am trying to set up backup verification with nakivos screenshot verification feature, however when the flash VM boot job recovers the VM i want to verify, the verification process always fails because the newly recovered vm doesn't automatically install/start vmware tools when being created.
Is there a way to automate installation of vmware tools with the vSphere7 webclient, or directly through the ESXi hosts ?